On the Celebrated Serenity Prayer---of St. Francis?
The famous "serenity prayer" reads something like this:

God, grant me the serenity to accept the things I cannot change, the courage to change the things I can, and the wisdom to know the difference.

Many Catholics seem to attribute the above to St. Francis of Assisi; however, it seems to me that the Protestant theologian Reinhold Niebuhr may have indeed authored it. See, for example, Original Serenity Prayer
QUESTION: Can anyone provide any evidence that the "serenity prayer" was known by anyone prior to Reinhold Niebuhr (1892--1971)? Can anyone suggest why it seems to have been long attributed to St. Francis of Assisi? Is there any evidence that St. Francis ever uttered or wrote it?
Thank you.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serenity_Prayer has a good writeup on the Prayer. Authorship of the Prayer has not been attributed to St Francis of Assisi.  Reinhold Niebuhr is generally referred to as its author. He is thought to have written the Prayer drawing inspiration from  Phil 4:6-7:
"  Do not be anxious about anything, but in every situation, by prayer and petition, with thanksgiving, present your requests to God.  And the peace of God, which transcends all understanding, will guard your hearts and your minds in Christ Jesus.".     https://www.nytimes.com/2008/07/11/us/11prayer.html#:~:text=Now%20the%20Serenity%20Prayer however, puts doubts on the origin of the prayer  pointing to the possibility of Niebuhr having compiled it from sources since forgotten by him ( In the 1980's, one could see the Prayer attributed to Cardinal John Henry Newman (1801-1890) who had joined Catholicism after having been an Anglican priest. Newman is the author of hymns like ' Lead, kindly light ')
